# Creating Choropleth Map using points in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, point, cartography, mapping, choropleth

As seen in the picture, the purple/yellow points represents yes/no, and the location of the points are based on home locations of the respondents.

[image]

In ArcGIS Pro I would like to create a choropleth map to represent the percentage of yes/no for each boundary.

How can I do that given that there are no common attributes?

Comment: Try Intersect or spatial join, then summary statistics, field calculate percentage, and join the results back to the polygons